# GNU screen terminates shortly after spawning it from a ssh session

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I have an alias to automate the following sequence of commands:

- ssh to remote server
- use screen to execute a java program

Something like this:

alias command='ssh -i [PATH TO PRIVATE KEY] -p [PORT] -t [USER@REMOTE_HOST] screen [SHELL SCRIPT THAT EXECUTES JAR FILE]

The alias works fine (as I see the screen running in remote computer after executing it) but the screen terminates shortly after executing the alias -- regardless of whether the screen is detached or not. Both client and remote computers are running on OSX.

However, if I execute the command manually in sequence (without alias to achieve all at once) by

- ssh -i [PATH TO PRIVATE KEY] -p [PORT] -t [USER@REMOTE_HOST]

then on the remote shell

- screen [SHELL SCRIPT THAT EXECUTES JAR]

the program within the screen is able to run to completion and exits normally without early termination.

It seems as if there is some process in the background that kills the screen when I execute the alias from the client computer. What could be the cause of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that ssh does not allocate a (pseudo-)terminal by default when passed a command to run.  The simplest way to make this work would be to pass the `-t` option to `ssh(1)`, which will tell SSH to allocate a terminal anyway (so long as `ssh(1)` has a controlling terminal).  This will allow everything to work the same way as when you separated the commands.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I actually passed -t into ssh(1) in my alias.

Below is what it looks like:

alias command='ssh -i [PATH TO PRIVATE KEY] -p [PORT] -t [USER@REMOTE_HOST] screen [SHELL SCRIPT THAT EXECUTES JAR FILE]

To clarify, the issue is that the screen will run as usual (as I see output of program on the screen), but after some short period of time (< 30 secs), it will terminate before the program finishes.

However, this does not happen if I manually ssh into remote computer and use screen to execute the program after that.